# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined - React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to set the new state with setState({index: index }) by passing the index but I got the following error

**"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"**
I'm using react hooks and also I'm using an arrow function, I do not really understand what's going on...

[image]

Any suggestion on how to fix this issue?

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";

const App = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    products: [
      {
        _id: "1",
        title: "Shoes",
        src: [
          "https://www.upsieutoc.com/images/2020/01/07/img2.png",
          "https://www.upsieutoc.com/images/2020/01/07/img2.png",
        ],
     
      },
    ],
    index: 0,
  });

  const { products, index } = state;
  console.log("index", index);

  const handleTab = (index) => {
    console.log("index", index);
    setState({ index: index });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {products.map((item) => (
       <div className="details" key={item._id}>
          <div >
            <img src={item.src[index]} alt="" />
          </div>

          <div>
        
            <div className="thumb">
              {item.src.map((img, indx) => (
                <img
                  src={img}
                  alt="img"
                  key={indx}
                  onClick={() => handleTab(indx)}
                />
              ))}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: `setState` from `useState` does not work the same way as the class component `this.setState`. You will need to specify the complete state when using `setState` i.e. `setState({ index: index });` should be `setState({ ...state, index: index });`

Comment: use state.products.map

Comment: you are storing products as an object in state. I will suggest you to have a look on hooks. and change the handletab code it will result an error if you click on the image

Comment: @Vibhav `state` is destructured in the line `const { products, index } = state;` so `state.products === products`.

Comment: by saying setState({ products, index: index }); it worked! Thanks to everyone

Comment: he is storing state value in a const. that's not why he is getting the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you setState({ index: index }) it remove the products property inside your state.
Then do it instead

```
setState({ products, index: index })
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is your products state is replace by index state in handleTap function. useState will replace the current state with new state if you don't include current state.

It will be better if you separate product state and index state. For example:

```
const [products, setProducts] = useState([
  {
    _id: "1",
    title: "Shoes",
    src: [
      "https://www.upsieutoc.com/images/2020/01/07/img2.png",
      "https://www.upsieutoc.com/images/2020/01/07/img2.png",
    ],
 
  },
])
const [index, setIndex]= useState(0);
```

then in your handleTab function just call setIndex to update the Index